# implement gradient descent with sparsification algorithm

Tags: signal-analysis, algorithms, self-study, compression

I am trying to implement the algorithm in [this paper](https://www.cse.iitd.ac.in/%7E%20rohitk/research/sparse.pdf) for finding a sparse vector x that minimizes the square error $\lVert y − \Phi x\rVert_2^2$ where $\Phi$ need to satisfy the restricted isometry property.

The gradient update rule is
$x\leftarrow\mathcal{H}_s(x+\gamma\Phi^{T}(y-\Phi x))$
where $\mathcal{H}_s(x)$ is the hard thresholding function that converts the last $n-s$ smallest elements of $x$ to $0$.

The definition of restricted isometry property is
$$(1-\delta_s)\lVert x\rVert_2^2\leq\lVert \Phi x\rVert_2^2\leq(1+\delta_s)\lVert x\rVert_2^2$$ for all $s$ sparse vector $x$. What can I do to find $\delta_s$?

```
GraDes <- function(A, y, s, rate = 0.5, tol = 0.00001) {
  # initialization
  Asize <- dim(A)
  x <- rep(0, Asize[2])
  
  diff <- 10
  
  iter <- 0
  while(diff > tol) {
    # compute gradient
    g <- -t(A)%*%(y-A%*%x)
    x <- x + rate*g
    
    # projection
    permute <- sort(abs(x), index.return = T)
    x[permute$ix[1:s]] <- 0
    
    # compute convergent criteria
    diff <- norm(y - A%*%x, type = "2")
    iter <- iter + 1

    if(iter > 1000) {
      print(x)
      break
    }
  }
  print(iter)
  print(diff)
  return(x)
}
```